# vba - deleting rows that don't contain specific word

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete rows that don't contain specific word in column Q and re calculate the sum row. Now this is part of the codes that I am designing so I am only posting this part since the rest of codes work just fine.

As for my data, I have a list of cites and their info and I added a column for their corresponding region (column Q) so I would like to filter the region I want to do analysis. For the total row, I need to re-calculate the numbers since it should only reflect the sum that are in the region.

My data range has merged headers and a total row so not sure if this will complicate the situation.

```
Sub test()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim x, lngLastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("A")
lngLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("Q5:Q" & lngLastRow - 1)
For x = Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If InStr(1, Rng.Cells(x, 17).Value, "NW") = 0 Then
Rng.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Now my current codes just delete everything excepts the merged header so I need help to filter for each region. And you can see that I haven't re-calculate the sum row as well since my codes have not worked so far so I haven't added that part yet.

Now, second method I have tried is to use filter function and it's giving me "Run Time Error 1004 AutoFilter method of Range class Failed" and this is the codes I tried.

```
   With ws.Range("B5", "Q" & lngLastRow)
   .AutoFilter
   .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="NW"
   End with
```

So I don't know which way will work better or if you guys have a different approach.

Here is a display of my data.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the column value in the line of code below to 1 instead of 17 like so:

```
If InStr(1, Rng.Cells(x, 1).Value, "NW") = 0 Then
```

This is because you are accessing the cells within the range you set previously, which only has 1 column: column Q.  So column Q is the first column of the Rng variable.  Column 17 is 17 columns from the first column in your range (column Q), which is column AG.  Your code would be selecting the correct column if you had written it as `ws.Cells(x, 17).Value` because then that would be the 17th column of the spreadsheet, as opposed to the 17th column of the range you set.

Comment: Thanks this is what i m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub FilterAndDeleteRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Range("B2:Q4").AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:="NW"
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Range("Q4:Q" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
    ws.Range("Q5:Q" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End If
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```