# Deleting one row (only if it is empty) before specific word

Tags: vba, ms-word

For the topic "VBA - WORD Deleting rows after and before specific word".

I almost need the same macro, I would like to delete one row before specific text (#N/A), but only if that row is empty.

```
Sub ScratchMacroIII()
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim para As Word.Paragraph
Dim found As Boolean

Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
With oRng.Find
  .Text = "#N/A"
  .wrap = wdFindStop
  found = .Execute
    Do While found
        Set para = oRng.Next(wdParagraph, -1).Paragraphs(1)
        para.Range.Delete
        oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        oRng.End = ActiveDocument.content.End
        found = oRng.Find.Execute
     Loop

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you're looking to use... I assume you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884018/vba-word-deleting-rows-after-and-before-specific-word)

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vba - deleting rows that don't contain specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375293/vba-deleting-rows-that-dont-contain-specific-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
  .Text = "#N/A"
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute = True
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      If .Cells(1).RowIndex > 1 Then
        With .Tables(1).Rows(.Cells(1).RowIndex - 1)
          If Len(.Range.Text) = .Cells.Count * 2 + 2 Then .Delete
        End With
      End If
    Else
      If .Paragraphs.First.Range.Start > 0 Then
        With .Paragraphs.First.Previous.Range.Paragraphs.First.Range
          If Len(.Text) = 1 Then .Delete
        End With
      End If
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It works great in table, but I don't have table just lines. Thank you.

Comment: Without wanting to place too fine a point on it, your question concerned *rows*, not *lines*. Only tables have rows.

Comment: You're right. I used that macro where they also used that term inaccurately.

Comment: Code updated to work both within tables and outside tables. I have not addressed the possibility that #N/A occurs immediately after a table. Do note that 'lines' have no meaning in Word, which works with paragraphs as the smallest regular unit comprised of one or more characters.

Comment: Wow!
:-)
That's what I was looking for.
Thank you so much.